# Deterministic Window/Desktop Manager Recommendation

Tags: macos, display, desktop, ventura

Is there any tool for macOS which can manage different app windows deterministically, especially when connecting and disconnecting from different external monitors? I use [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) and it kinda works if I do not connect/disconnect monitors, but as soon as I do, the desktops shifts to different screens and even sometimes flip between external monitor and the MacBook inbuilt display.

For example, If I have Chrome Window 1 in inbuilt display(Full Screen) on desktop 1, and a slack window and Chrome Window 2 in external display on Desktop 10 (left half slack, right half chrome). Then I want to keep these windows in the same desktop and the same desktops in the same screens.

I am on macOS Ventura (13.0.1) if it matters. I would not mind paying for this functionality, although open source is always welcome. Compatibility with Rectangle is bonus.